# Is this too convoluted to be acceptable?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I am writing a Befunge interpreter. I was curious how bad the style in this method is.

```
def adv(r, c, dir, torus)
  case dir
  when 0; r == 0 ? (return torus.n_o_l - 1, c) : (return r - 1, c)
  when 1; c == torus.r_l - 1 ? (return r, 0) : (return r, c + 1)
  when 2; r == torus.n_o_l - 1 ? (return 0, c) : (return r + 1, c)
  when 3; c == 0 ? (return r, torus.r_l - 1) : (return r, c - 1)
  end
end
```

I know how to reformat it if I just need to use a more standard if/else construct, but I was curious how awful this would look in source code.

Comment: it's not super-awful, but you also won't get any prizes for readability. would recommend not using "?" and rewriting as return blah if ; return blah 2

Comment: What does this code doing?

Comment: @asiniy 'adv' is short for 'advance', and it's moving the theoretical pointer in Befunge '93. It's not as simple as just moving in a direction because you're supposed to have a toroidal array in Befunge '93. It more or less just makes sure there are no out of bounds errors.

Comment: `I personally like my code to be as short as possible, readable or not.` Don't.

Comment: @Mast, can you elaborate? I tend to agree with you, but mostly for selfish reasons. However, I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing for readers to have to work a bit to understand (good) code that's written concisely, as there's educational value in doing so.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP is asking for what's acceptable. He admits `readability is favored over brevity`. Educational value is irrelevant if other people have to use your code. Maintainability and usability are essential and should be maintained as 'best-practice'. We have a [dedicated StackExchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) dedicated to improving (among other things) those two.

Comment: @Mast, ha! I originally thought "I personally...or not." was your position (and that "Don't" was don't change your code). Just the opposite!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is terrible. I would do it like this:

```
def adv(r, c, dir, torus)
  case dir
  when 0
    r = torus.n_o_l if r.zero?
    [r - 1, c]
  when 1
    c = -1 if c == torus.r_l - 1
    [r, c + 1]
  when 2
    r = -1 if r == torus.n_o_l - 1
    [r + 1, c]
  when 3
    c = torus.r_l if c.zero?
    [r, c - 1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent, mainly because of the way you have exposed the (probably important) patterns in the return values (which I had missed).  I suggest "terrible" rather than "horrible".

Comment: very clean solution.. 1+

Comment: "Your code is horrible." And your comment is blunt. Honest, though.

Answer (score 1):

My try:

```
def adv(r, c, dir, torus)
  case dir
  when 0; r == 0 ? [torus.n_o_l - 1, c] : [r - 1, c]
  when 1; c == torus.r_l - 1 ? [r, 0] : [r, c + 1]
  when 2; r == torus.n_o_l - 1 ? [0, c] : [r + 1, c]
  when 3; c == 0 ? [r, torus.r_l - 1] : [r, c - 1]
  end
end
```

Omit `return` because `case` always returns something by default.

Comment: You could use `then` instead of `;` to separate case condition from the specific code.

Comment: hfenan wants the code as short as possible =) I don't know why

Comment: @asiniy there's really not a good reason, I just like really short code.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd at least strip each operation out into its own method. Ignoring the brevity argument for the moment, my main reason would be so that I can test each operation independently from the case statement.

```
def adv(r, c, dir, torus)
  case dir
  when 0; op1(r, c, torus)
  when 1; op2(r, c, torus)
  when 2; op3(r, c, torus)
  when 3; op4(r, c, torus)
  end
end

def op0(r, c, torus)
  r == 0 ? [torus.n_o_l - 1, c] : [r - 1, c]
end

def op1(r, c, torus)
  c == torus.r_l - 1 ? [r, 0] : [r, c + 1]
end

def op2(r, c, torus)
  r == torus.n_o_l - 1 ? [0, c] : [r + 1, c]
end

def op3(r, c, torus)
  c == 0 ? [r, torus.r_l - 1] : [r, c - 1]
end
```

As for "I personally like my code to be as short as possible", you obviously haven't learnt that you should [code like the next developer looking at your code is a psychopath who knows where you live](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/).

Don't worry - you will learn.

Comment: I liked your approach, as it is well OOP.. :)

Comment: I hate this! Hate it! Hate it! Positively hate it! It's from the school of *the-more-the-number-of-really-tiny-methods-the-better*. That drives me crazy. Wait, I'm already crazy. What's your address, Reegie? I'd like to just drop by and say hello.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an opinion, so your question may not be long for this world, but here's my suggestion:

```
def adv(r, c, dir, torus)
  case dir
  when 0
    case r
    when 0 then             [torus.n_o_l-1, c]
    else                    [r-1, c]  
    end
  when 1
    case c     
    when torus.r_l-1 then   [r, 0]
    else                    [r, c+1]
  when 2
    case r
    when torus.n_o_l-1 then [0, c]
    else                    [r+1, c]
  when 3
    case c
    when 0 then             [r, torus.r_l-1]
    else                    [r, c-1]
  end
end
```

Sometimes what one wants to do just can't be simplified. I expect that's the case here. If you can't break it down into pieces, you can at least think about how we humans process information we read. I found your code hard to follow because the return values were visually mixed in with the conditional statements. I addressed that by putting all the return values in a column. For each value of `dir` in the case statement, you can have `if ... else ... end` or `... ? ... : ...` or a secondary case statement. I selected the last of these simply because I thought it was easiest to read and resulted in the least amount of distracting "code-clutter".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using better names for variables - what is `r`, what is `c`?

I recently wrote a ['readable' Befunge interpreter](https://github.com/rohitpaulk/befunge-ruby), in which I added a  human friendly constant for directions. It looked [like this](https://github.com/rohitpaulk/befunge-ruby/blob/026de10ea7c9e49be81d46f1c820fa974c1a5860/lib/befunger/interpreter.rb#L36).

```
DIRECTIONS = {
  right: { x: 1, y: 0 },
  down:  { x: 0, y: 1 },
  left:  { x: -1, y: 0 },
  up:    { x: 0, y: -1 }
}
```

Given that constant, calculating the next position for an instruction (called `code_pointer` below) is as easy as this:

```
# Moves the `code_pointer` in the specified `code_direction`, and returns the modified
# `code_pointer`
#
# @param code_pointer [Hash] the current +code_pointer+, in the form: `{x: 0, y: 3}`
# @param code_direction [Hash] the current +code_direction+, in the form: `{x: 0, y: 1}`
# @return [Hash] the modified `code_pointer`
def move_pointer(code_pointer, code_direction)
  code_pointer[:x] += code_direction[:x]
  code_pointer[:y] += code_direction[:y]

  code_pointer
end
```